# Nginx config subdomain exhibiting strange behaviour

Tags: nginx, security, configuration

I've got two identical droplets running on digital ocean. Both running Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx, gunicorn and Django.

I am trying to park a subdomain of mine onto the IP of one of the droplets. On the other droplet, I have parked a subdomain successfully, and it works as intended.

Right now, the problem droplet seems to be only able connect correctly through the IP address of the droplet. By visiting the IP address, the gunicorn instance can be seen perfectly and the proxy to the gunicorn port `:9000` isn't required to access it.

By accessing the subdomain that I have added an A record for in my domain registrar pointing to the IP of this droplet, I am greeted by an nginx welcome page saying that nginx needs more configuration.

By accessing the subdomain and appending the gunicorn port `:9000` I am greeted by the Django app, however it is not serving the static files like it does when visiting the IP address of the droplet. Also if I visit the IP address and append the `:9000` port it has the same effect.

My config for nginx are identical on both droplets the only difference is the IP address within `server_name`.

```
server {
    server_name *.*.*.*;
    access_log off;

    location /static {
        alias /opt/venv/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /opt/venv/media;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://$server_name:9000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

I've also attempted setting server_name to the subdomain also, to no avail.

Am I missing something? Why does this work on one droplet but not the other?

**EDIT: Added config for gunicorn**

```
command = '/opt/venv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/opt/venv/fjarrtoolbox'
bind = '127.0.0.1:9000'
workers = 3
```

Comment: Are you setting server name to an IP address or a domain name? The way it looks above is IP notation. When you say "droplet" is this a proprietary name for a virtual server? Would you be comfortable posting the actual domain names and the exact configs for nginx? Could it be something to do with the way gunicorn is configured, or do they both work fine when accessed directly by IP?

Comment: They both work fine when accessed by IP. also the virtual server that works correctly has the IP address set as the server_name and that works as expected. If I set the server_name to the subdomain nginx returns a 502 error.

Comment: Why do you have an A record if you're addressing them by IP? I'm not sure you're meant to put an IP in there : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name. Please consider answering all the questions I asked in my first question.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
proxy_pass http://$server_name:9000;
```

Should be:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
```

That change will efficiently and securely route the traffic to the backend through the local loopback interface.

Also, Gunicorn should be configured to bind to port 127.0.0.1, since it only intended to be accessed through Nginx. You are inviting additional problems by exposing it to the public if you don't need to.

Here's what can go wrong with your current configuration. Someone can send a request to your server with a third party host name like this:

```
curl -H 'Host: example.com' http://1.2.3.4/Hello
```

Your `server_name` will accept requests matching any host name, so the requests will be processed, then the request will be proxied to "example.com" on their port "9000". Let's say this is someone else's Gunicorn server that also left port 9000 open. Now there's potentially attack traffic being sent to that Gunicorn server, originating from your IP address, as you are running a form of open proxy.

That's why it's good to use explicit values for `server_name`, for the `proxy_pass` host and why your backend servers should explicitly bind to port 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I've done the above, but the subdomain still only gets a configure page for nginx, and now the IP address just times out. I've updated the original question with my gunicorn configuration.